# How do I copy my Stack Overflow profile to all the sites of Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: support, user-profile

How I can copy my Stack Overflow profile to all the sites of this network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the accounts tab on your profile page - https://stackoverflow.com/users/720176/amit-dwivedi?tab=accounts you should see three links/buttons:

> Copy Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts
>
> Clear all Stack Exchange account associations
>
> Copy Stack Overflow login credentials to all Stack Exchange sites.

Click on the first link.

If you want your Programmers information copying do the same but from your Programmers account - https://stackoverflow.com/users/720176/amit-dwivedi?tab=accounts

Comment: thanks.....but reputations and badges wont be copied this way ?

Comment: @Amit Reputation and badges are separate by site. They never carry over

Comment: ok... thanks for the information